# Validar Control File de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estoy utilizando un Plugin (http://develoteca.com/bootstrap-file-input-archivos-utilizando-html5/) para subir archivos ya logre que funcione, tengo 2 dudas:

-Como hago para validar que exista un archivo seleccionado para el envio, el boton del submit para subir el archivo lo genera el plugin por lo que no se como agregar el evento, me imagino que se hara en la parte del Javascript donde se seleccionan las extensiones el archivo que procesara etc. pero no se cual es la instrucción.

-Mi otra duda es como le cambio el idioma.

Si alguien tiene experiencia con este plugin,le agradecería bastante su ayuda.

el código es el siguiente:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Krajee JQuery Plugins - &copy; Kartik</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/fileinput.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/fileinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Bootstrap File Input Example</h1>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="file-1" type="file" class="file" multiple=true data-preview-file-type="any">
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$("#file-1").fileinput({
    showCaption: false,
    browseClass: "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
    fileType: "any"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Se configura con ese Script que apunta al fileinput, buscando he encontrado varias opciones, pero no encuentro como añadirle un evento al boton upload que crea el Plugin.

Comment: es de leer mas el repo https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput, aqui mas info http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Comment: Problema solucionado utilizando otros metodos. gracias.

Comment: por favor cierra la pregunta o eliminala